# Sorting of row is not working in jquery sortable plugin

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table which contain rows. Each row have one toggle button and it is toggle with one other row. Now I applied sortable plugin to only rows which have sortable class like  items: 'tr.sortable-row'. The sorting is performed correct when toggle is off means child row is hidden. But when toggle is ON then I am able to drag the row but not able to drop it target position. Please suggest.

Comment: Where is the code?  A demo of this UI issue in jsfiddle.net would also help

Comment: The problem is may be container not getting size to shift the row.

Comment: nobody can help without code and demo